# how to know the frequency of audio from microphone

Tags: python, audio, frequency

i am in trial of creating an app with python which displays the exact value of present dominating frequency of audio from microphone input.just like as shown in this picture taken from a guitar tuner app

[image]

i just marked with red the part which i need to know how to program.
i need to run it in PC so how to access the microphone port and how to know the frequency.

Comment: So, you basically don't have anything? Have you at least tried to do something?

Comment: SO is not an advice forums. What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: @JamesZ yah i tried to rrcord and then take fourier transform.now i need is to make it in real time

Answer (score 1):

Find a way of recording your audio from the mic port and then run a Fourier transform to look at the spectrum. Find the frequency that has the most energy and plot that on the meter.

Comment: Thank u nimish i have done it already what u suggested iam looking for a code that displays the frequency in real time .u can understand if u try the app.thank u in advance

Answer (score 1):

I won't provide code since you have not shown anything at your end.
But here are high-level steps and hints to go do it.

1) Use `pyaudio [blocking wire stream](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#wire-example) to read input from microphone in the form of chunks [ pieces].

2) For each chunk , apply `fft` and get frequency for all the chunks and add to an array/list.
There are some useful discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674877/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624548/fft-real-imaginary-abs-parts-interpretation)
So if you have following parameters as per (1)

```
RATE = 44100
chunk = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 1
```

You will have 44 bins, with each bins providing one frequency after `FFT` transformations.

3) You can select maximum frequency `max(frequency_list)` that you get from (2) per second, Times how many seconds you wish to record.

4)  Write the [chunks back to stream](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#wire-example)

5) You have now frequency per second till time duration of your recording in real-time that you can play with.